# How can we use SET statement inside CASE while updating different records in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, set, case

```
UPDATE dbo.TestStudents  
SET LASTNAME = 
( CASE  
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'AAA') THEN 'BBB' 
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'CCC') THEN 'DDD' 
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'EEE') THEN 'FFF' 
ELSE  (LASTNAME)
END )
```

This statement works fine if we update only one column.
But I am interested in updating different columns on different CASE condition.
Just like below:-

```
UPDATE dbo.TestStudents       
( CASE  
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'AAA') THEN SET FIRSTNAME ='BBB' 
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'CCC') THEN SET MODDLENAME ='DDD' 
WHEN (LASTNAME = 'EEE') THEN SET NAME ='FFF' 
ELSE  (LASTNAME)
END )
WHERE X = Y
```

So is there any way to run this command ? or IF ELSE is the last resort.
Can Somebody Help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update each column individually and use case accordingly:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE  dbo.TestStudents       
    SET     FIRSTNAME = CASE WHEN LASTNAME = 'AAA' THEN 'BBB' ELSE LASTNAME END
            ,MIDDLENAME = CASE WHEN LASTNAME = 'CCC' THEN 'DDD' ELSE LASTNAME END
            ,NAME = CASE WHEN LASTNAME = 'EEE' THEN 'FFF' ELSE LASTNAME END
    WHERE   X = Y
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a different `case` statement for each column

```
UPDATE dbo.TestStudents
SET    FIRSTNAME = CASE
                     WHEN LASTNAME = 'AAA' THEN 'BBB'
                     ELSE FIRSTNAME
                   END,
       MODDLENAME = CASE
                      WHEN LASTNAME = 'CCC' THEN 'DDD'
                      ELSE MODDLENAME
                    END,
       NAME = CASE
                WHEN LASTNAME = 'EEE' THEN 'FFF'
                ELSE NAME
              END
WHERE  X = Y
```

Comment: I think we are loosing the concept of using CASE in your solution. I think IF ELSE is much handy if we have only one condition. My idea of using CASE is with multiple conditions, although conditions are based on one variable only(LASTNAME)

Comment: @ashish - Not sure what you are expecting. Can you add sample data and expected output.

Answer (score -1):

You can use;

```
UPDATE 
dbo.TestStudents  
SET 
(
FIRSTNAME = ( CASE WHEN (LASTNAME = 'AAA') THEN 'BBB' ELSE  (LASTNAME) END `),
MODDLENAME = ( CASE WHEN (LASTNAME = 'CCC') THEN 'DDD' ELSE  (LASTNAME) END ),
NAME = ( CASE WHEN (LASTNAME = 'EEE') THEN 'FFF' ELSE  (LASTNAME) END )
)
WHERE X=Y
```

`